# Loop optimization in R

Tags: r, for-loop, image-processing, apply

So... I'm trying to optimize for loppings in R.

My problem is: I have a multidimensional array (6 layers) and I want to get a matrix as answer.
For each cell position (i,j) I need to apply a function that uses the 6 values in the position i,j and returns for the probability for each pixel.

My first idea was to create two nested for-loops scanning each pixel position and applying this function. However, as my matrix has many elements (approximately 2000 x 2000 x 6), it is taking TOO long to calculate the function at each pixel position.  I would like to know if there is any way to optimize this calculation. I tried using the "apply" function using both dimensions as parameters of MARGIN {`MARGIN = c(1,2)`} but apparently I'm computing something wrong.

Below is an example of the first version of my code:

```
data <- c(
  8247, 9240, 8875, 20534, 14334, 10797,
  8090, 9081, 8364, 21301, 13496, 9599,
  8089, 8922, 8620, 19769, 13601, 9749,
  8477, 9554, 9383, 18693, 14649, 10498,
  8476, 9711, 9637, 17616, 14649, 10348,
  8164, 8921, 8873, 16844, 12763, 9449,
  8008, 8285, 8106, 17309, 12239, 8999,
  7929, 8445, 7977, 19003, 12449, 8999,
  7850, 8284, 7977, 18080, 12345, 8850,
  8083, 8443, 7976, 19158, 12449, 8999,
  8401, 9713, 9638, 18691, 14858, 10947,
  8400, 9555, 9257, 18846, 14544, 10498,
  8399, 9239, 9256, 18077, 15068, 10947,
  8477, 9554, 9510, 17924, 15382, 11096,
  8397, 9711, 9637, 17770, 14859, 10648,
  8164, 9238, 8873, 18079, 13183, 9749,
  7852, 8603, 8106, 18695, 12449, 9150,
  7774, 8603, 7977, 18850, 12449, 8999,
  7773, 8444, 8105, 18235, 12345, 8999,
  7849, 8443, 8104, 18235, 12449, 9300,
  8556, 9713, 9893, 18230, 15277, 11246,
  8632, 9712, 9893, 17769, 15591, 10947,
  8631, 9397, 9638, 17461, 16324, 11546,
  8476, 9396, 9383, 17924, 15591, 11397,
  8553, 9553, 9637, 18078, 14649, 10648,
  8163, 8920, 8873, 17771, 13078, 9898,
  7852, 8603, 8105, 18542, 12555, 8999,
  7851, 8444, 8105, 19311, 12659, 8999,
  7772, 8444, 8104, 18851, 12555, 8999,
  7771, 8443, 8104, 19005, 12555, 8999,
  8478, 9871, 10020, 17615, 15068, 10948,
  8632, 9712, 10020, 17615, 15381, 11246,
  8554, 9554, 9766, 17461, 15382, 11096,
  8476, 9554, 9510, 17924, 15172, 11097,
  8397, 9553, 9383, 17462, 15278, 11097,
  8086, 9078, 8745, 18849, 13812, 10199,
  7695, 8761, 8233, 20233, 13079, 9150,
  7851, 8602, 8233, 20387, 12869, 9450,
  7927, 8602, 8104, 20388, 12869, 9150,
  7926, 8760, 8232, 20849, 13393, 9599,
  8633, 9871, 9893, 17461, 15278, 11247,
  8633, 9713, 10020, 17308, 15278, 11247,
  8477, 9870, 9893, 17615, 15172, 11246,
  8708, 9711, 9637, 17616, 15172, 10947,
  8397, 9238, 9382, 17462, 15068, 10797,
  8086, 8920, 8745, 18695, 14126, 10199,
  7929, 8919, 8233, 20847, 13393, 9150,
  7850, 8919, 8360, 20847, 13393, 8999,
  7927, 8760, 8232, 20848, 13183, 9450,
  7926, 8759, 8231, 20849, 13289, 9450,
  8710, 9713, 10020, 17770, 15278, 11097,
  8632, 9713, 9893, 17770, 15173, 11098,
  8476, 9870, 9893, 18079, 15069, 11247,
  8397, 9711, 9765, 17770, 15068, 10947,
  8164, 9238, 9128, 17771, 14545, 10648,
  8085, 8920, 8361, 19003, 13602, 9898,
  8007, 8919, 8361, 20847, 13393, 9150,
  7927, 8919, 8360, 20848, 13497, 9300,
  7927, 8760, 8360, 21155, 13393, 9450,
  7848, 8759, 8231, 20543, 13393, 9450,
  8556, 9871, 9893, 17462, 14963, 11097,
  8555, 9713, 9893, 17462, 14964, 11098,
  8632, 9712, 9766, 17771, 15279, 11098,
  8554, 9712, 9511, 18388, 14650, 10648,
  8319, 9395, 9128, 20386, 13916, 10199,
  8085, 9078, 8489, 20693, 13602, 9599,
  8084, 8919, 8233, 21307, 13497, 9300,
  8006, 8919, 8232, 21614, 13393, 9450,
  8005, 8760, 8232, 21155, 13393, 8999,
  8004, 8759, 8103, 20543, 13079, 9450,
  8633, 9870, 9893, 17308, 15278, 11247,
  8555, 9870, 10020, 17462, 15173, 11098,
  8554, 9555, 9511, 18233, 14860, 10948,
  8009, 8922, 8618, 19926, 13917, 10199,
  7852, 8604, 8106, 21766, 13498, 9599,
  8007, 8761, 8233, 21306, 13497, 9300,
  7928, 8761, 8232, 21001, 13497, 9150,
  7849, 8602, 8232, 20388, 13183, 9300,
  7926, 8601, 8231, 20235, 13183, 9150,
  7770, 8601, 8103, 20083, 13184, 9150,
  8323, 9397, 9257, 19156, 14963, 10797,
  8399, 9396, 9257, 18849, 15279, 10797,
  8243, 9238, 8873, 20079, 14336, 10049,
  7853, 8604, 8234, 20234, 13288, 9150,
  8008, 8445, 8106, 20235, 13078, 9300,
  7928, 8444, 8105, 19927, 12973, 9300,
  7850, 8444, 8105, 18389, 12869, 9300,
  7849, 8602, 8232, 18389, 12764, 9300,
  7848, 8442, 8231, 20082, 12659, 9450,
  7847, 8442, 8103, 20390, 12869, 9150,
  8090, 8764, 8492, 20232, 13183, 9300,
  8011, 8605, 8364, 19925, 13183, 9300,
  7932, 8446, 8107, 19926, 13078, 9150,
  8009, 8445, 7978, 19158, 12764, 9000,
  7930, 8603, 8105, 19313, 12555, 9150,
  7929, 8603, 8233, 19928, 12660, 9300,
  7927, 8444, 7976, 19312, 12555, 8999,
  7849, 8601, 8104, 19159, 12555, 8850,
  7848, 8442, 8103, 20082, 13079, 9300,
  7925, 8600, 8103, 20390, 13289, 9300
)

image <- array(data, dim = c(10, 10, 6))

num_classes = 2

params<- vector("list", num_classes)
mean_vector1 = c(7889.362,  8412.398,  8046.333, 17008.465, 11883.484,  8895.631)
mean_vector2 = c(8055.359,  8979.759,  8421.408, 21060.805, 13810.918,  9664.242)

covariance_matrix1 = matrix(c(
  9004.794,  3393.195,  3512.241,  11185.344,  8613.778,  4262.351,
  3393.195,  12405.309,  6722.598,  33555.189,  15467.398,  6200.901,
  3512.241,  6722.598,  14015.815,  21658.040,  15597.915,  8170.201,
  11185.344, 33555.189, 21658.040, 567199.44, 161168.165, 46471.445,
  8613.778, 15467.398, 15597.915, 161168.16, 137379.407, 45141.111,
  4262.351, 6200.901, 8170.201, 46471.44, 45141.111, 35420.010
), nrow = 6, byrow = TRUE)

covariance_matrix2 = matrix(c(
  13137.14, 16641.66, 13388.65, 53306.99, 42323.70, 24993.38,
  16641.66, 50107.41, 32027.36, 136436.34, 96649.78, 54599.03,
  13388.65, 32027.36, 33801.94, 66746.02, 75361.02, 45798.90,
  53306.99, 136436.34, 66746.02, 1037747.24, 418523.62, 203725.86,
  42323.70, 96649.78, 75361.02, 418523.62, 306097.86, 167889.17,
  24993.38, 54599.03, 45798.90, 203725.86, 167889.17, 115735.97
), nrow = 6, byrow = TRUE)

params[[1]] <- list(mean = mean_vector1, covariance_matrix = covariance_matrix1)
params[[2]] <- list(mean = mean_vector2, covariance_matrix = covariance_matrix2)

classified_image <- matrix(0, nrow(image), ncol(image))

for (row in 1:nrow(image)) {
  for (col in 1:ncol(image)) {
    pixel <- image[row, col,]
    class_probabilities <- numeric(num_classes)
    
    # Calcular probabilidades para cada classe
    for (i in 1:num_classes) {
      parameters <- params[[i]]
      class_probabilities[i] <- gaussian_probability(pixel,parameters)
    }
    
    # Atribuir a classe com maior probabilidade
    max_prob_class <- which.max(class_probabilities)
    classified_image[row, col] <- max_prob_class
  }
}

gaussian_probability <- function(pixel,parameters){
  mean_vector = parameters$mean
  d=6
  covariance_matrix=parameters$covariance_matrix
  det_cov <- det(covariance_matrix)
  inv_cov <- solve(covariance_matrix)
  
  exponent = -0.5 * (pixel - mean_vector) %*% inv_cov %*% as.vector(t(pixel - mean_vector))
  coef = 1 /sqrt(((2*pi)^d)*det_cov)
  
  probability = coef * exp(exponent)
  
  return(probability)}
```

In my second version, I'm trying to use something like this (just to show what I'm trying to do):

```
image_probabilities <- array(0, dim = c(10, 10, num_classes))

for (i in 1:num_classes){
  parameters <- params[[i]]
  image_probabilities[[i]] <- gaussian_class_likelihood(image,parameters)}

  
gaussian_class_likelihood <- function(image, parameters){
  image.array = as.array(image) 
    
  probability_image <- apply(image.array, MARGIN = c(1,2),  function(pixel) {
    class_probabilities <- gaussian_probability(pixel, parameters)
      return(class_probabilities)
    })
    return(probability_image)}
```

The first approach is impractical because of the amount of time it takes to calculate each pixel...Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Without digging much, there are many optimization opportunities. 1) You calculate `inv_cov` for each pixel, but you could just calculate it once and pass the inverse to your function 2) Same for `det_conv` 3) Inside your function you calculate twice `pixel - mean_vector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the final product is `classified_image`, rather than the probabilities for each pixel. The solution below uses three strategies:

1. Vectorization. The calculations will be much, much faster when done all at once. The only loops needed are over the classes.
2. Some of the probabilities are very small. To maintain precision (and simplify the calculations), use the *log* probabilities instead.
3. Since the probabilities are only compared to each other, you need only something that is *proportional* to the probabilities (or log probabilities) being compared (e.g., multiplying two probabilities by `sqrt((2*pi)^6)` does not affect the result of a comparison to determine which one is larger, and neither does taking the square root of both probabilities). If the actual probabilities are needed for some other portion of the code not shown in the question, completing the calculations is straightforward.

Applying the two solutions as functions to compare timings:

Proposed solution:

```
f2 <- function() {
  image2 <- matrix(image, 6, 100, 1)
  mean_vector <- list(mean_vector1, mean_vector2)
  covariance_matrix <- list(covariance_matrix1, covariance_matrix2)
  image_centered <- lapply(mean_vector, \(v) image2 - v)
  det_cov <- lapply(covariance_matrix, det)
  inv_cov <- lapply(covariance_matrix, solve)
  # get the image classifications
  matrix(
    max.col(
      -mapply(
        function(i) {
          rowSums(
            crossprod(image_centered[[i]], inv_cov[[i]])*t(image_centered[[i]])
          ) + log(det_cov[[i]])
        },
        1:num_classes
      ), "f"
    ), 10, 10
  )
}
```

Original solution (modified to use log probabilities):

```
f1 <- function() {
  params <- vector("list", num_classes)
  params[[1]] <- list(mean = mean_vector1, covariance_matrix = covariance_matrix1)
  params[[2]] <- list(mean = mean_vector2, covariance_matrix = covariance_matrix2)
  
  classified_image <- matrix(0L, nrow(image), ncol(image))

  gaussian_probability <- function(pixel,parameters){
    mean_vector = parameters$mean
    d=6
    covariance_matrix=parameters$covariance_matrix
    det_cov <- det(covariance_matrix)
    inv_cov <- solve(covariance_matrix)
    return(-(pixel - mean_vector) %*% inv_cov %*% as.vector(t(pixel - mean_vector)) - log(det_cov))
  }
  
  for (row in 1:nrow(image)) {
    for (col in 1:ncol(image)) {
      pixel <- image[row, col,]
      class_probabilities <- numeric(num_classes)
      
      # Calcular probabilidades para cada classe
      for (i in 1:num_classes) {
        parameters <- params[[i]]
        class_probabilities[i] <- gaussian_probability(pixel,parameters)
      }
      
      # Atribuir a classe com maior probabilidade
      max_prob_class <- which.max(class_probabilities)
      classified_image[row, col] <- max_prob_class
    }
  }
  
  classified_image
}
```

Timing (and checking that the results are identical):

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f1(),
  f2(),
  check = "identical"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr    min      lq     mean median      uq    max neval
#>  f1() 4874.0 5122.95 5697.924 5341.0 5706.90 8474.6   100
#>  f2()  104.5  120.35  156.873  147.1  184.05  299.9   100
```

Comment: Thank you, jblood94... When you did "image2 <- matrix(image, 6, 100, 1)", are you transforming each band in a line? 
Like, for the general case I should use matrix(image,num_bands, nrow*ncol, 1), right?

Comment: Another question, are the results not identical?

Comment: Yes, generally, `matrix(image,num_bands, nrow*ncol, 1)` should work. The two results are identical, otherwise `microbenchmark` would error because `check = "identical"`.

Comment: is there a way to store the probabilities for each class? besides the classification what I really need is the image_probabilities.  
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The `-mapply` returns the log of `sqrt((2*pi)^6)` times the square of the probability, so you could change the `-mapply(` line to be `probabilities <- -mapply(`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your apply approach and it works, you should check for performance, all I did was to move the class loop in the function.

```
gaussian_probability <- function(pixel){
  class_probabilities <- numeric(num_classes)
  for (i in 1:num_classes) {
    parameters <- params[[i]]
    
    d=6
    mean_vector = parameters$mean
    covariance_matrix=parameters$covariance_matrix
    det_cov <- det(covariance_matrix)
    inv_cov <- solve(covariance_matrix)
    
    exponent = -0.5 * (pixel - mean_vector) %*% inv_cov %*% as.vector(t(pixel - mean_vector))
    coef = 1 /sqrt(((2*pi)^d)*det_cov)
    
    class_probabilities[i] = coef * exp(exponent)
  }
  which.max(class_probabilities)
}

apply(image,MARGIN=c(1,2),gaussian_probability)
```

I am sure there is a better way of doing this and there probably exists a function already (a very simple optimization is to NOT `solve` the same covariance matrix in each loop).